# call specific query only from all queries file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

i am making a php website. there are tons of queries so i decided to put all of them in a seperate file and execute what i need at the moment.

i need a way to call a statement so that only that statement is called not the whole file. i was using require_once to include this file in every page and so i can call `stmt2->execute()`; or any other stmt to execute but it caused a problem that in any case if this `allstmts.php` file contains a fatal error it is shown in each and every other page because this file is included in it by require_once

how can i stop that? and call only a query not whole file in every page can #define work in this case?

file: `allstmts.php`

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `$database`.`$mem` (`parent_id`, `placedby`, `name`, `dob`, `sex`, `username`, `email`, `mob`, `pass`, `jointime`, `plan`, `rank`, `cloud`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt2->bind_param("iisssssssssss", 2, $parent_id, $name, $dob, $sex, $username, $email, $mob, $pass, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $plan, 'mitra', $newfile);
```

there are more queries like this in above file stmt3, stmt4, stmt5, etc etc

Comment: Honestly, I feel like doing this should be some kind of taboo. Create a file called ex: "sql_functions.php" and create a function for each query. Or create a class that does queries for you, include it once and go from there.

Comment: is it possible to bind new parameter to previously created prepared statement? @Dimi

Answer (score 2):

> i decided to put all of them in a seperate file

So now you can tell it was a **really bad move**.

This is like having two cars in a garage but for some reason have wheels detached and stored in a different place. Yes, that's a lot of wheels, but a wheel belongs to its car, not to its kind. All your queries  belong to their module, not to their kind.

Please dismantle that monster sql file and put all queries where they belong.

And in any case you should **never prepare all queries at once**. It will make your site to work slow and overload your database. Only prepare a query that is going to be executed.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest you use ORM like eloquent for project , before its too late and you can not understand what is where. but this is your solution :

```
<?php
define( 'DB_NAME' , 'ciw' );
define( 'DB_USER' , 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD' , 'root' );
define( 'DB_HOST' , 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET' , 'utf8' );

// Create connection to database using PDO
global $connection, $lastQuery;
try 
{
    #$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8", $user, $pass);

    $connection = new PDO( "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=".DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD );
//    var_dump ($connection);

    // Set PDO error mode to exception:
    $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//    echo "Conneted to DB Successfully";
}
catch( PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " .$e->getMessage();
}
```

then build a functions.php file to put your helper functions :

```
function sql_runner( $sql , $inputs = [] )
{
    global $connection , $lastQuery;

    try {

        $lastQuery = $connection -> prepare( $sql );
        $lastQuery -> execute( $inputs );
        return $lastQuery;


    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e -> getMessage();
    }
}
```

then need a select and select all function like follow :

```
function sql_runner_fetch( $sql , $inputs = [] )
{
    return sql_runner( $sql , $inputs ) -> fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```

```
function sql_runner_fetch_all( $sql , $inputs = [] )
{
    return sql_runner( $sql , $inputs ) -> fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```

if you needed to count the rows :

```
function sql_runner_rowCount( $count = -1 )
{
    global $lastQuery;
    try {
        if( $count == -1 ) {
            return $lastQuery -> rowCount();
        }
        return $lastQuery -> rowCount() == $count;
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e -> getMessage();
    }

}
```

get the last query id :

```
function lastInsertedID()
{
    global $connection;
    return $connection -> lastInsertId();
}
```

check if it is uniqe :

```
function is_unique( $table , $column , $value )
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` = ?";
    sql_runner_fetch_all( $sql , [ $value ] );

    if( sql_runner_rowCount( 0 ) ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

i hope you understand how to add your own functions.

whenever you need to call a query just do this :

```
$stmt = " SELECT *,`users`.`id` AS `users_id` FROM  `users`";
$users = sql_runner_fetch_all($stmt);
```

you can handle statements with a statement builder file. but this is just a working way , not the right one.

Comment: That's a more or less usable approach please read up on the principles of [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). They are severely violated in your code.

Comment: oh and that `global`ised magic with $lastQuery is absolutely unacceptable. Ironically, it is misused in your code. instead of `if( sql_runner_rowCount( 0 ) ) {` you can do ` if(sql_runner_fetch_all( $sql , [ $value ] ))` already. but you shouldn't really.

Comment: if you see the last line i mentioned that it is just working , not the best or even the right way , but tnx any way for checking